# How to make textarea resizeable in the ASP.NET MVC project template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the existing template of the ASP.NET MVC project, but I have a `textarea` field that I want it to be resizable in both directions with minimum height and width.
I'm using `EditorFor` in the markup and specified `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` in the model class.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm new to bootstrap, but using the page inspector I found that the margin taking the whole width and I can't change its value, I changed the `height` value and it works but with fixed width:

```
textarea.form-control {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px;
    resize: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using razor syntax, so you could try this for the TextArea:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { @class = "form-control" })
```